# Handling PHP ^C CLI Script

Tags: signals, php

I have a php script that runs in the background 24/7. I have to occasionally terminate it, and the point of the script is to cache transaction data to memcahced from bitcoin RPC (if you don't know what that is, it is irrelevant). I want the script to execute a function when the program receives the signal sent on ^C (control C).

Answer (score 22):

You probably want [`pcntl_signal`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php).  The signal you need to catch is `SIGINT`.

Comment: Note: This was literally 2 seconds of Googling.

Comment: I'd give you +0.1 for the small amount of effort, but looks like I'll have to settle for +1.0. ;-)

Comment: I just wanted to ask people who actually know something about this, instead of going down the wrong path, and screwing up my script. I am pretty sure I have come across pcntl_signal before, but didn't understand that you could use it like this.

Comment: Two seconds of Googling now brings up this answer first! +1

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody else is looking, I've found an answer that doesn't require pcntl_signal.

You can use `system("stty intr ^-");` to stop `^C` from exiting the script automatically. You can then capture it as `ord(fread(STDIN, 1)) == 3` within PHP, and handle exiting manually.

I'm working on a [library](https://github.com/bellows-io/Cli/blob/b0b69e867b55407e8ec50582ad33e5f765ea19c2/src/Terminal/Ansi.php#L161) that does this.